# When i am running the below code in Rasperi Pi Pycharm i am getting a error(Python 3.5).But works fine in windows pycharm

Tags: python, sockets, pickle, communication, eoferror

```
reply = s.recv(1024)

ip_buying_inter = pickle.loads(reply)

print('Internal Buying Price', repr(ip_buying_inter))

reply = s.recv(1024)

ip_selling_inter = pickle.loads(reply)

print('Internal Selling Price', repr(ip_selling_inter))
```

**Error Message**
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/Mtecg/test3.py", line 73, in

```
ip_selling_inter = pickle.loads(reply)
```

EOFError: Ran out of input

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reproduce the issue based on the information in the question. But it it seems that pickle complains about not getting enough data for unpacking which might be due to `recv` not returning the full "message".

It looks like that you are assuming that you will get the full pickled message with a single `recv`. This does not need to be the case: TCP is not a message protocol but cares only about a byte stream. And a `send` on the sender side might need multiple `recv` on the  receiver site in order to reconstruct the full message.

If a single `recv` will return the full message used in `send` depends on multiple factors: latency of the connection, MTU (which differs between communication on localhost vs. communication on Ethernet or WLAN), speed of the systems ... - and this might explain that it seems to work with pycharm on Windows but not on the RasPi.